# Download file using terminal in mac OS (with redirecting URLs)

Tags: macos, terminal, scripting

Need a little help.

URL1. 
https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-esr-latest-ssl&os=osx&lang=en-US

URL2. 
https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/68.7.0esr/mac/en-US/Firefox%2068.7.0esr.dmg

On browser, URL1 gets redirected to URL2 to download Firefox ESR.
I am able to download the file using the second URL but its not working with URL1.

curl -o ~/Downloads/Temp/Firefox.dmg https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/68.7.0esr/mac/en-US/Firefox%2068.7.0esr.dmg

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

`curl -L FirstURL -o myfile`

In long form:

`curl --location https://google.com --output myfile`

Comment: Working perfectly fine..
Thank you so much @Richard Barber